# bug report rosserial arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot file a bugreport because I cannot get into Trac, so here it is:

The latest release of rosserial for arduino (downloaded it 30 december) is not capable of subscribing to std_msgs/uint16 or std_msgs/uint8.

I wrote a program to test it. subscribe to and publish the same value. This will not work for uint16, but std_msgs::int16 was okay. The code will compile correctly but on the Arduino it gets misinterpreted (some value is read, which changes also!).

I suspect that the definition of UInt16.h in the std_msgs-directory in Arduino is not okay because it has changed . It used to have definition:

```
  union {
    signed char real;
    unsigned char base;
  } u_data;
```

and now not anymore.

But that does not hold because publishing uints with the new version is not a problem!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12547/bug-report-rosserial-arduino/) by [edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/1253/edward/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a duplicate of https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/ticket/53

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To post to the Trac, you need to create a Kforge account. If you have already created an account and cannot add a bug, let me know so we can get that fixed.

As to the specific bug here, I just patched it in trunk. It will likely take a few days to make it into debs.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1